# Get dat column in App Script without time zone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the date into App Scripts but eventually, it is getting a date with time and time zone which I really don't want to.
here is what I code.

```
function sendMail(){
var first = 0;
var order = 1;
var date = 2;
var item = 3;
var email = 4;
var pesa = 5;
var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();

var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("NAJ");

var data = ws.getRange("A2:F" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

data.forEach(function(row){
  emailTemp.fn = row[first]
  emailTemp.oid = row[order]
  emailTemp.odate = row[date]
  emailTemp.itm = row[item]
  emailTemp.amt = row[pesa]
  var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    row[email],
    "Your Order Recently Canceled",
    "Your email doesn't support HTML",
    {'from':aliases[4], name: "My company name", htmlBody: htmlMessage}
    );
  });
}
```

this showing the date in below format

`Thu Feb 25 2021 14:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

i only want it to be

```
25/01/2021
or
01/25/2021
```

Here is the HTML

```
<p>Hi <?= fn ?>,</p>
  <p>I hope you are well. We notices you recently tried to place an order on <a href="www.xyz.com">My Company Name</a>, and it got canceled before completion.</p>
  <p>Let me know if you need any assistance with placing an order; I will be delighted to help you.</p>

  <p>Below is your canceled order details:</p>

  <p><strong>Order# <?= oid ?></strong></p>
  <p><strong>Date: <?= odate ?></strong></p>
  <p><strong>Item: <?= itm ?></strong></p>
  <p><strong>Total Amount: $<?= amt ?></strong></p>
```

any help will highly be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear where you get the date in the code you shared, but you can format the date as you wish by using the formatDate() method from the [Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) class.

Try somehting like this:

```
let formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy")
Logger.log(formattedDate)
```

and see if that works for you?

EDIT: Here's the complete code for you to try. Note: The html-body is constructed inside the code. No need for a seperate HTML-file.

```js
function sendMail() {
  let [first, order, date, item, email, pesa, aliases] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, GmailApp.getAliases()]
  let data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("NAJ").getDataRange().offset(1, 0).getValues();

  data.forEach(row => {

    let formattedDate = isDate_(row[date]) ? Utilities.formatDate(row[date], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy") : "";
    let htmlMessage = getHTMLBody_(row[first], row[order], formattedDate, row[item], row[pesa])

    if (row[email]) {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[email], "Your Order Recently Canceled", "",
        {'from':aliases[4], name: "My company name", htmlBody: htmlMessage }
      );
    }
  });
}

function getHTMLBody_(fn, oid, odate, itm, amt) {

  return '<HTML><p>Hi ' + fn + ',</p>' +
    '<p>I hope you are well. We notices you recently tried to place an order on <a href="www.xyz.com">My Company Name</a> ' +
    'and it got canceled before completion.</p>' +
    '<p>Let me know if you need any assistance with placing an order; I will be delighted to help you.</p>' +
    '<p>Below is your canceled order details:</p>' +
    '<p><strong>Order# ' + oid + '</strong></p>' +
    '<p><strong>Date: ' + odate + '</strong></p>' +
    '<p><strong>Item: ' + itm + '</strong></p>' +
    '<p><strong>Total Amount: ' + amt + '</strong></p>' +
    '</HTML>';
}

function isDate_(d) {
  return (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) !== "[object Date]") ? false : (isNaN(d.getTime())) ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: i have updated the full code. i want to put the date in HTML. don't know how to let your variable go there.

Comment: Where are 'order', 'item' and 'pesa' defined in your code.gs ?

Comment: They are coming from the Google Spread Sheet.

Comment: Sorry i just updated it again. those does not matter btw. i need the date to be formatted

Comment: sorry but its givving me Invalid email: Email  Code.gs:11 and 5 error

Comment: Hi, It's hard to comment on that without seeing the data. Try adding a console.log as the first line in the if-statement and check the values of row[email].

Comment: I also added an offset(1, 0) after the datarange to skip the header row. Check if that helps?